# Anyone knows how to deploy AFNetworking extensions in an iOS project?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, afnetworking, cocoapods

I just installed the AFNetworking library by cocoapods. Actually, I'd like to use the AFOAuth2Client extension, now I have no idea on how to install this extension by cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually broken out into a [separate spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/AFOAuth2Client/0.1.2/AFOAuth2Client.podspec.json). You will just want to add that to your `Podfile`. You can actually remove `AFNetworking` from it because dependencies are automatically handled by CocoaPods.